# Changing Polling times on a VM running under Server2012 R2?

Tags: hyper-v, time, gps

Is there a way to know or change the polling times of VMs running under a Hyper-V 2012 R2 server?  We have set all the hosts and physical domain controllers to keep time with our new GPS time server on location.  WE have read to keep the VMs set to keep time from the host.  How often does that occur from Microsoft, and if it is more than 15 minutes, how do we manually set it?

Thanks in advance for any help!